# Fast caramelized taste for soup

Tags: caramelization

I want to make soup, a random soup. 
suppose that I want to to give it a deep taste, like a caramelized onion taste.

because I only need the taste, I don't care about texture.
can I get the equivalent of caramelized onion fast? like, 15 minute fast?

I read somewhere that I can brown onion fast if I fry it first without oil,salt or anything, destroying interior speed up the process of carammelizing and browning.

or is giving the soup a storebought caramel bar able to give equivalent deep taste? 
or caramelized carrots, garlics? 
I only need the caramelized taste, because the main flavour will be from spice and herbs.
the question is this:
what are the fast ways (under 16minutes) to give a soup a deep,caramelized taste?

Comment: Add a splash of vinegar to your onions as they cook.

Comment: Make a big batch of caramelized onions in advance. Once they're caramelized, they'll last quite a long time in the fridge (at least a couple weeks in my experience) and you can add them to your dishes as desired.

Comment: Add baking soda. There's a video on it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npZosJvE1nU

Comment: Adding to what @danc said, you could even freeze them in blocks.

Comment: I've just caramelized 2 onions and a splash of malt vinegar in under 10min over the highest heat my stove goes to. Just don't stir too often, but just enough to stop them burning.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a little bit of sugar to your onions while cooking them; this will help them get caramelized faster. (or at least get some caramel flavors).

But you will need to check them often in order not to burn the sugar too much.

Answer (score 1):

A pressure cooker is a great way to get fast caramelized onions, carrots, or other sugary vegetables.

It could be done in 15 at pressure, but it takes time to get up to pressure, and to release the pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know about rapidly caramelizing onions: http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/01/the-food-lab-real-french-onion-dip-homemade-super-bowl-recipe.html

In summary, the suggested method involves heating the onions in the skillet with melted sugar, butter, baking soda and salt on a medium heat for six to eight minutes and then deglazing with water.

This method takes between 18-26 minutes.

Comment: Please try to avoid link-only answers since pages on external sites can be moved or deleted without our noticing. For this reason link-only answers are usually deleted. If you edit your question and add a summary of the information behind the link, your answer may attract up-votes instead.

Answer (score 0):

1/8 to 1/4 tsp of baking soda per onion will speed up the Millard reaction significantly

It will leave a soapy taste though, so you may need some acid (viniegar) or sugar to neutralise it at the end of the cooking process

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat idiotproof way to caramelize onions in the microwave:

http://altonbrown.com/how-to-make-caramelized-onions-in-the-microwave/

And you can freeze those for quite a while.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! As you are not new to the SE concept, would you please add the main instructions from the link to the answer itself? Once the link becomes obsolete, we will only know that there *exists* a method, but not, how to do it.